# When is a str not a str?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have an issue in Python3 where a `str` is not a `str`. I'm working through a 2to3 project, and I'm getting a failure due to a type check in a third party class. For what it's worth this didn't happen under Python 2. The following example does not error but is similar to my issue:

```py
class TheirClass():
    # I don't love that they're using `id` here, but they are
    def __init__(self, name, id=None):
        if isinstance(name, str):
            self.name = name
        else:
            raise TypeError('name is not a str')

my_object = TheirClass('a name')
print('Yep that worked')
```

I haven't yet been able to reduce this to a `MCVE`, but I do know the following things:

- I am passing a `str` into the constructor for `TheirClass.name`
- Outside `TheirClass.__init__` `isinstance(name, str) == True`
- Inside `TheirClass.__init__` `isinstance(name, str) == False`
- Inside `TheirClass.__init__` `type(name)` returns `<class str>`
- Inside `TheirClass.__init__` `dir(name) == dir(str)`
- `inspect.getmro` reports that my pseudo-str doesn't have an `__mro__`
- After renaming `id` in their code I was able to see that `id(str) != id(type(name))`
- The `id` of the `name` object does not change between the two method calls

As far as I can tell nobody is redefining `isinstance` or `str`. But the `id` of `str` **does** change from outside constructor of `TheirClass` to inside of it.

Comment: `TheirClass()` is now `YourClass()` you've got to own it and improve it

Comment: True enough. And I originally thought that the problem might have had something to do with how I was subclassing TheirClass into MyClass. But it turns out that:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final clue was that the `id` of `str` changed. While there was no assignment of `str` or `def str` there was an import. Specifically:

```py
from past.builtins import str
```

Comment: This would have been my first question; check if `str` is still bound to the built-in.

Comment: So the object expects a `bytes` string, not a Unicode text string.